# Changing Django login validation

Tags: python, django

I want to alter the login_required method to be able to address to different urls when it is not validated. Python 3.6.1 & Django 1.11

```
def login_dece(function):
 def _inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
    u = request.user
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        u.is_authenticated and Dece.objects.filter(id=u.id).exists(),
        login_url=settings.LOGIN_URL,
        redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
 return _inner

url(r'^sgd$', login_dece(sys.sgd), name='sgd'),
```

Comment: What do you want to alter, and to what? Can you be more specific.

Comment: I want to alter the login_required method to be able to address to different urls when it is not validated.

Comment: maybe you mean HttpResponseRedirect?

Comment: Several urls, by different case, or the same url in case of fail?